# Translation of "hotness points", as used by the Hot Network Questions' algorithm?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

In the Stack Exchange network there is an algorithm to determine which questions are featured in "[Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)", the list of popular questions. As a result of this formula you get points called "hotness points".

A quite literal translation for "hotness point" might be *"puntos de calidez"*, but it does not make any sense since we are talking about popular questions that generate interest. With this in mind an option might be *"puntos de popularidad"*, just like *[StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)* translates "Hot Network Questions" as *"Preguntas populares en la red"*.

What do you think would be the best translation for "hotness points" in Spanish?

Comment: Estoy plenamente de acuerdo con _puntos de popularidad_ ya que eso es lo que se mide. ¿Qué no te gusta de esa traducción? No veo porque reinventar el agua tibia. :-)

Comment: @DGaleano No digo que no me guste, se me ocurrió mientras redactaba la pregunta y lo puse como ejemplo. En SOes pone "preguntas populares" pero los puntos pueden llamarse de otra forma, en el chat surgieron diferentes ideas y quería saber que piensa la comunidad sobre esto.

Comment: Gee,  am I the only one who interpreted "Hotness points" to be closer to "picante" than to "caliente"?  (PS, I don''t know how to nominalize "picante").

Comment: Beware that the colloquial and metaphorical meanings of "hot" don't translate well into most romance languages. For example, "estar caliente" (una persona) is unrelated to "be hot" (somebody), and [Some like it hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Some_Like_It_Hot) doesn't make much sense in Spanish.

Comment: @Pere, it doesn't make much sense in English (except in the sense in which it's used in a nursery rhyme about pease porridge).

Answer (score 6):

Aunque jocosamente yo los suelo llamar "puntos de calentura", una traducción tal vez más correcta sería **puntos de actualidad**.

Creo que el hecho de que una pregunta (o una noticia) sea "hot" es porque está de actualidad y en boca de todos (está "caliente" o "candente", cual bollo recién salido del horno). Por hacer énfasis en el hecho de que la pregunta está de actualidad (tiene mucha actividad y votos favorables), es por lo que hago mi propuesta.

Comment: ¿Por qué no *puntos de [candencia](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=candencia)*? ;-)

Comment: @pablodf76 pues no está mal. Puedes ponerla en una respuesta aparte para que quien pregunta tenga más donde elegir. :-)

Comment: De las "alternativas" esta es la que más me gusta +1 aunque considero que la mejor traducción sigue siendo la que SO en español está usando _puntos de popularidad_

Comment: @pablodf76 no había visto tu comentario cuando he escrito mi respuesta. Me suena un poco raro pero es bastante precisa tu traducción a mi entender.

Comment: @blonfu Es precisa pero no la he planteado como respuesta porque no creo que sea muy usable. *Candencia* es una palabra rara, parece casi una broma.

Answer (score 6):

Allow me to introduce the concept of ***"calentómetro"***: from **["caliente"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6nrQsN4#KtXLYFy)**, in its meaning of "heated, alive" used for arguments; and **["-metro"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P8UAjhT)**, a suffix meaning "to meter" or "metering device".

So a "**calentómetro**" would be a device to gauge the "hotness" of something, in this case a question and the answers it generates.

It would be used like this:

> *¡Esta pregunta tiene 148 puntos en el **calentómetro**!*

Comment: Tengo que admitir que me gusta tambien esta respuesta.

Comment: Off-topic: ¿Cómo decidís de añadir o no un guión a una nueva palabra?

Comment: El **calentómetro** es una App para "conocer los diversos niveles de compatibilidad sexual entre dos personas" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companyname.kalentometro&hl=es. Te robaron la idea :-)  Ya esta palabra la han usado muchos pero parece que siempre con connotación sexual.

Comment: Let me introduce you the greek term word *[thermos](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/termo-)* (well, not with this alphabet, but sounds like that) which means "hot" (or *caliente*). Maybe we could join this word with the *metro* particle to mean an instrument to measure how hot things are: *termómetro*!!. "Calentómetro" is an abomination that belongs to the dungeons of marketing.

Answer (score 4):

Añado una idea más con un término que aparece en la respuesta de @CarlosAlejo: "puntos candentes",  que sigue manteniendo la referencia al calor (puntos al rojo vivo) y es además algo que está de actualidad, de moda, en el candelero.

Aunque posiblemente lo correcto sería "puntos de candencia" suena un poco raro.

Comment: Es más o menos lo que intentaba decir menos el sentido de un fuego de grande tamaño. 'candente' suena mejor.

Comment: y ¿porqué hay que mantener la referencia al calor? Las buenas traducciones mantienen la idea, no las palabras.

Comment: Es cierto que no tiene porque pero en español también se entiende lo caliente como algo reciente, del momento y me parecía bien señalarlo como refuerzo de la idea.

Answer (score 3):

Una interpretación más libre podría ser *puntos de llamarada*. En las redes sociales es típico asociar "hotness" con fuego en los íconos. Por ejemplo (sacado de Reddit):

[image]

El pensamiento es que una pregunta con actividad febril arda más calidamente que preguntas olvidadas.

Answer (score 3):

Estoy pensando que ya tenemos una palabra para indicar "puntos de calor": **¡[grados](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JOxCcBX#5ZvVEcR)!**

Los *hotness points* van de 0 a 100. Por encima de 100, la pregunta aparece en las HNQ, y por debajo no.
De manera similar, los grados centígrados están basados en las temperaturas de congelación y ebullición del agua, donde por encima de 100 grados el agua esta hirviendo y por debajo no.

> Esta pregunta está a 154 grados.

Esto viene que ni pintado para la metáfora de que una pregunta muy popular *está que hierve*...
¿No?

¿Nadie?

Answer (score 3):

Even in English, "Hot" is just a informal way of saying "Popular"<sup>1</sup>. In Spanish, "Caliente" simply does not have that meaning, even informally, if you see it used that way used somewhere is just due to to improper translations from English. "Candente" does have both meanings, but nowadays it is sheldom used to refer to temperature.

So, we should be looking translations that mean "Popular", not "Caliente". The best I can think of is the original term "Puntos de popularidad" (after all, there must be a reason for "Hot Network Questions" becoming "Preguntas populares en la red" and not "Preguntas calientes en la red"<sup>2</sup>

Other valid terms for "popular" are:

1. candente (already in another answer)
2. (de) moda.
3. notorio.

Options 1. and 2. sound strange when you add the "points" part ("puntos de candencia", "puntos de moda") and 3. ("puntos de notoriedad") does not improve over "puntos de popularidad" and is way less common.

Another possible option could be "interés", but it does not exactly mean the same and, additionally, it has other meaning (like "interés" in a loan).

Another alternative approach for this specific case is to take a wider meaning and equate "hotness/popularity" with "activity" (after all, this is how hotness is measured, isn't it?) and go with "puntos de actividad".

So, stick with "Puntos de popularidad".

---

<sup>1</sup>Not that I blame them, if I had a language with the same lack of consistence in pronunciation I would try to ditch all the words with more than one syllabe, too.

<sup>2</sup>Which, when you factor out that "Caliente" does not mean "Popular" and that "Caliente" may mean "Sexy, Attractive", makes the former form more palatable to a porn site than for a "vanilla" one.

Comment: As I said in my comments to the question... _puntos de popularidad_